# Why Array cannot add prototype with literals?

Tags: javascript

```
var a=[1,2,3,4]

function Demo(){}

Array.prototype={
  foo:function(){
    alert(1)
  }
}//a.foo is not a function

Array.prototype.foo=function(){
  alert(1)
}//alert(1)

a.foo()

Demo.prototype={
  foo:function(){
    alert(1)
  }
}

var b=new Demo()
b.foo()//alert(1)
```

Why can't `Array` add prototype with literals? Also, why does it work when I use a constructor?

Here is an example:
https://jsbin.com/zowalu/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot replace the `Array.prototype` object (which is what you are trying to do in the first example), as `Array.prototype` is read-only.

Your second example works because you are simply *adding a key* to the prototype, not replacing it.

The third example works, because `Demo` is an object of your design, whereby the prototype is not read-only.

Comment: Thanks,i know,you mean i try  to replace all in first example

Comment: Even if the first case worked, *a* is constructed before the replacement of *Array.prototype* so would still reference the original *prototype* anyway.